# Seaborn (time series) boxplot using hue and different scale axes

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, seaborn, boxplot

I have a dataframe which has a number of values per date (datetime field). This values are classified in U (*users*) and S (*session*) by using a column *Group*. Seaborn is used to visualize two boxplots per date, where the hue is set to *Group*.

The problem comes when considering that the values corresponding to U (*users*) are much bigger than those corresponding to S (*session*), making the S data illegible. Thus, I need to come up with a solution that allows me to plot both series (U and S) in the same figure in an understandable manner.

I wonder if independent Y axes (with different scales) can be set to each hue, so that both Y axes are shown (as when using `twinx` but without losing hue visualization capabilities).

Any other alternative would be welcome =)

The S boxplot time series boxplot:

[image: The S boxplot time series boxplot]

The combined boxplot time series using hue. Obviously it's not possible to see any information about the S group because of the scale of the Y axis:

[image: The combined boxplot time series using hue. Obviously it's not possible to see any information about the S group because of the scale of the Y axis]

The columns of the dataframe:

| Day (datetime) | n_data (numeric) | Group (S or U)|

The code line generating the combined boxplot:

```
seaborn.boxplot(ax=ax,x='Day', y='n_data', hue='Group', data=df, 
                palette='PRGn', showfliers=False)
```

---

Managed to find a solution by using twinx:

```
fig,ax= plt.subplots(figsize=(50,10))

tmpU = groups.copy() 
tmpU.loc[tmp['Group']!='U','n_data'] = np.nan

tmpS = grupos.copy()
tmpS.loc[tmp['Group']!='S','n_data'] = np.nan

ax=seaborn.boxplot(ax=ax,x='Day', y = 'n_data', hue='Group', data=tmpU, palette = 'PRGn', showfliers=False)

ax2 = ax.twinx()

seaborn.boxplot(ax=ax2,x='Day', y = 'n_data', hue='Group', data=tmpS, palette = 'PRGn', showfliers=False)

handles,labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
l= plt.legend(handles[0:2],labels[0:2],loc=1)

plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(),rotation=30,horizontalalignment='right')
for label in ax.get_xticklabels()[::2]:
    label.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
plt.close('all')
```

The code above generates the following figure:

[image: the following figure.]

Which in this case turns out to be too dense to be published. Therefore I would adopt a visualization based in subplots, as Parfait susgested in his/her answer.

It wasn't an obvious solution to me so I would like to thank Parfait for his/her answer.

Comment: Please show code. Please include data sample. Please even screenshot the problem plot.

Comment: I've added the line generating the combinedplot, the images I'm refering to and explained the head of the pandas dataframe I'm ploting. Don't hesitate to ask any questions or for any further detail that might help to solve my question. In addition, I know that what I'm asking can be done using R.

Answer (score 2):

Consider building separate plots on same figure with y-axes ranges tailored to subsetted data. Below demonstrates with random data seeded for reproducibility (for readers of this post).

**Data** *(with U values higher than S values)*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(2018)
u_df = pd.DataFrame({'Day': pd.date_range('2016-10-01', periods=10)\
                              .append(pd.date_range('2016-10-01', periods=10)),
                     'n_data': np.random.uniform(0,800,20),
                     'Group': 'U'})

s_df = pd.DataFrame({'Day':  pd.date_range('2016-10-01', periods=10)\
                               .append(pd.date_range('2016-10-01', periods=10)),
                     'n_data': np.random.uniform(0,200,20),
                     'Group': 'S'})

df = pd.concat([u_df, s_df], ignore_index=True)
df['Day'] = df['Day'].astype('str')
```

**Plot**

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

for i,g in enumerate(df.groupby('Group')):                
    plt.title('N_data of {}'.format(g[0]))    
    plt.subplot(2, 1, i+1) 

    seaborn.boxplot(x="Day", y="n_data", data=g[1], palette="PRGn", showfliers=False)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
plt.clf()
plt.close('all')
```

[image: Box Plot Output without Hue]

---

To retain original hue and grouping, render all non-group *n_data* to `np.nan`:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

for i,g in enumerate(df.Group.unique()):             
    plt.subplot(2, 1, i+1)  

    tmp = df.copy()
    tmp.loc[tmp['Group']!=g, 'n_data'] = np.nan

    seaborn.boxplot(x="Day", y="n_data", hue="Group", data=tmp,
                    palette="PRGn", showfliers=False)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
plt.clf()
plt.close('all')
```

[image: Box Plot Output with Hue]

Answer (score 2):

So one option to do a grouped box plot with two separate axis is to use `hue_order= ['value, np.nan]` in your argument for `sns.boxplot`:

```html
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))

ax = sns.boxplot(x="lon_bucketed", y="value", data=m, hue='name', hue_order=['co2',np.nan],
                 width=0.75,showmeans=True,meanprops={"marker":"s","markerfacecolor":"black", "markeredgecolor":"black"},linewidth=0.5 ,palette = customPalette)
ax2 = ax.twinx()

ax2 = sns.boxplot(ax=ax2,x="lon_bucketed", y="value", data=m, hue='name', hue_order=[np.nan,'g_xco2'],
                 width=0.75,showmeans=True,meanprops={"marker":"s","markerfacecolor":"black", "markeredgecolor":"black"},linewidth=0.5, palette = customPalette)
ax1.grid(alpha=0.5, which = 'major')
plt.tight_layout()
ax.legend_.remove()
GW = mpatches.Patch(color='seagreen', label='$CO_2$')
WW = mpatches.Patch(color='mediumaquamarine', label='$XCO_2$')

ax, ax2.legend(handles=[GW,WW], loc='upper right',prop={'size': 14}, fontsize=12)

ax.set_title("$XCO_2$ vs. $CO_2$",fontsize=18)
ax.set_xlabel('Longitude [\u00b0]',fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel('$CO_2$ [ppm]',fontsize=14)
ax2.set_ylabel('$XCO_2$ [ppm]',fontsize=14)
ax.tick_params(labelsize=14)
```

[image]